# Finding a dharma teacher

Tags: teachers, dharmas

I am examining ways of going further on my dharma road. At this point i am entirely self taught, for better and worse. I strongly believe that from here, some form of guidance from a more experienced teacher could help. Preferably face to face if possible.

Does anyone know if there is someone committed to teaching in west sweden?

Also, is there a sangha (anywhere in the world, really) that formalizes dharma teaching in some form of curriculum? I think a more structured approach could help my western mind learn dharma.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have a [Guide](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?cb=1) and a [Resource section](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) for new users that you might like.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, i'll check out the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erik,

If the are Sanghas (of the Buddha's monks - a mixed or lay community shouldn't be called a "Sangha") or possible one or another monk alone, it's good to visit them, observe them, and to ask them -- if it's the case that you can trace a good amount of independence between the monk[s] and the "students" (e.g. the monks don't live from students, and instead go for alms independently). If such a person is traced, one might ask questions on any matter of doubt, having found trust, to possibly gain right view. If having gained right view after listening the true Dhamma, there is no more much to worry and the path will develop step by step.

If not finding such, take, if given by a Monk personally (!), the Tipitaka. Usual ways, although common, seldom or never bear any fruits, and it's far better to simply avoid the many teachers who teach for a trade (i.e. for reward). Even if they knew what water was, you would only get an empty bottle: to be sure you would have to return to them!

Maybe this is your personal guide heading toward independence: [Into the Stream](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/study/into_the_stream_en.html)

And for the case that Erik has already found firm faith, it is because of doing it to an end that the Buddha has found this religion, Sangha, open to make use of it and such might then be not so much a matter of "west Sweden".

*[Note: This is not given for any trade, exchange, stacks or what ever ordinary gains within the world.]*

Answer (score 0):

I've seen other people/answers recommend the [World Buddhist Directory](http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/country.php?country_id=74).

Though there may be another more Sweden-specific directory, this "World" directory was about as complete as any other local/national directory that I found online in 'my' country.

Answer (score 0):

**I strongly believe that from here, some form of guidance from a more experienced teacher could help. Preferably face to face if possible.**

You have to first finalise which school you are most comfortable with, whether Theravada (South Asia, mostly Srilanka, Thailand), Vajrayana(Tibetians) or Mahayana(Zen) ( China, Japan ) (West has all).

Also, that ways people on this site will be able to guide you to exact teacher you are looking for.

**Also, is there a sangha (anywhere in the world, really) that formalizes dharma teaching in some form of curriculum? I think a more structured approach could help my western mind learn dharma.**

Tibetean schools has structured programs something akin to PhD's of university degrees but that will need you to learn Tibetean language.

Theravada offers best structured approach. You can have a look at Ajahn Brahm's monastery in Australia. They might have some program for you. There are some monasteries in Thailand, which offer shorttime-stay-monk-lives and teachings for westerners.

From your question it looks like Zen approach wont suit you. But still, if you are in Sweden you might want to check [Plum Village](https://plumvillage.org) in France.

I dont think there will be a curricullum for lay buddhists that can be offered by a monastery. Very often the monks will give teachings based on 'you'. But for any curriculum you will have to first choose a school. For an acedemic study an e-sangha like this site is best. Take a look at questions on book recommendations on this site.

Answer (score -1):

> Also, is there a sangha (anywhere in the world, really) that formalizes dharma teaching in some form of curriculum?

There's Ven. Bodhi's lecture series on the Majjhima Nikaya and the on-going series on the Anguttara Nikaya (livestream every Saturday morning 10AM Eastern US time). More info. is available from the baus.org web site and their youtube channel at https://www.youtube.com/user/venbodhi

Comment: You're welcome, Erik. Question for @ChrisW, recently someone continuously downvote all of my posts for no reason. While I don't really care about the point system, I do care about confronting trolling activity on the forum and suspect someone is actively engaging in sabotaging the forum environment. I'm sure you moderators folks can easily track down the troll and take the proper action. Thanks.